# How does one use the "Content" field type in KeystoneJS?

Tags: keystonejs

How does one use the [Content field type](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/field-content/) in KeystoneJS? I've put the following in my index.js, following the example given in the link above:

```
keystone.createList('Todo', {
    schemaDoc: 'A list of things which need to be done',
    fields: {
        name: {type: Text, schemaDoc: 'This is the thing you need to do'},
        blip: {type: Text, schemaDoc: 'This is another thing'},
        status: {type: Select, options: 'pending, processed'},
        rating: { type: Stars, starCount: 5 },         body: {
            type: Content,
            blocks: [
                Content.blocks.blockquote,
                Content.blocks.image,
                Content.blocks.link,
                Content.blocks.orderedList,
                Content.blocks.unorderedList,
                Content.blocks.heading,
                // CloudinaryImage.blocks.image,
            ],
        },
    },
```

But when I go to the front end and click on the '+' button there, it only offers me the option of inserting an image (see screenshot below)

What is it I'm supposed to be seeing?  If I'm supposed to see more, what am I supposed to be doing?  I don't see anything about 'blockquote', 'link', 'orderedList', etc....

Is this all superceded by the Wysiwyg editor?  Or do they do different things?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

you have to write some text and then select that text for text formatting items.

this is how it looks with all options on:

[image]

this is how it looks when I remove the extra formatting option (bare content field)
[image]